# standard normal random variable

Tags: probability

S​uppose X is a continuous random variable with mean 1 and variance 4, Y
is a standard normal random variable, that is Y∼N(0,1). Assume X and  Y are independent. What is the mathematical expectation of X exp(Y)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(Xe^Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{y-y^2/2}dy=\frac{e^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y-1)^2/2}dy=e^{1/2}$

Note - independence and $E(X)=1$ are used.

Comment: W​hat is the variance of X exp(Y)?

Comment: @Jeferson Use standard formula: $E((Xe^Y)^2)-E(Xe^Y)^2=E(X^2)E(e^{2Y})-E(X)^2E(e^Y)^2$.